# ListView isnt updating state after I added a FutureBuilder

Tags: dart, flutter

Before this problem happen I was dealing with Future handling to return the values I saved on a sharedPreference, however my _deleteTodo method was working just fine.
After I added the FutureBuilder and finally  got my values rendered on the UI now I'm struggling with this new bug.
Every time I update the state of and item my UI reflects it but immediately undoes it

I tried to see if it was something with my _deleteTodo method so I changed the setState to only change the boolean from false to true, but it does exactly the same. 
I also print the length of my List after the _deleteTodo and something funny happens: it works one time, the _deleteTodo erase the Todo but after that it doesn't work anymore

```
This is my TODO class     
class Todo  {
Todo ({this.title,this.isDone = false});
String title;
bool isDone;


//Decode method to convert a Json String into a Dynamic object
Todo.fromJson(Map <String, dynamic> json)
: title = json ["title"],
  isDone  = json ["isDone"];
Map <String,dynamic> toJson() =>
{
      "title" : title,
   "isDone" : isDone
};
 }
```

This is my screen

```
class _TodoListScreenState extends State<TodoListScreen> {
  List<Todo> todos = [];




//updates the state of the checkbox and reflects it on the UI
  _toggleTodo(Todo todo, bool isChecked) {
    setState(() {
      todo.isDone = isChecked;
  _deleteTodo(todo,isChecked);
  print(todos.length);

    });
  }

   _addTodo() async {
    final todo = await showDialog<Todo>(
      context: context,
     builder: (BuildContext context) { // <- Here you draw the 
 Dialog
         return NewTodoDialog();
  },
);
    if (todo != null) {
  setState(() {
    todos.add(todo);
    _saveTodo(todos);
    print(todos.length);
     });
    }
   }
  _deleteTodo (Todo todo, bool isDone)  => (isDone)?  
 todos.remove(todo): debugPrint;


  //Save you array object as an array of Strings in Shared Preferences
  Future<void> _saveTodo(List<Todo> todo) async {
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await 
  SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  sharedPreferences.setStringList("savedData", _mapTodoData(todo));
  }

 _mapTodoData(List<dynamic> todos)  {

    try {
     var res = todos.map((v) => json.encode(v)).toList();
      return res;
    } catch (err) {
      // Just in case
      return ["Nope"];
   }
   }

  Future<List> loadData() async {
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await 
  SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final List<Todo> todoArray =
  _decodeTodoData(sharedPreferences.
 getStringList("savedData")).toList();
  todos = todoArray;

    return todoArray;
  }

      List<Todo> _decodeTodoData(List<String> todos) {
    try {
      //Transforming List<String> to Json
      var result = todos.map((v) => json.decode(v)).toList();
      //Transforming the Json into Array<Todo>
      var todObjects = result.map((v) => Todo.fromJson(v)).toList();
      return todObjects;
    } catch (error) {
      return [];
   }
  }






  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
      title: Text('Todo List')),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(

            future: loadData(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
      return TodoList(
          todos: todos,

          onTodoToggle: _toggleTodo,
          );
    })
  )
  ,
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent[700],
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: _addTodo,
  ),
);
   }

  }
```

Thanks in advance, hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell is that your `_deleteTodo` deletes from the local instance list `todos` but you are instructing flutter to rebuild the UI from disk via `loadData` which re-gets the data from disk.

My suggestion is to get the data once on page load using `initState` and from there only refer to the local instance of `todos`.

In your `_deleteTodo` you would also need to persist the state to disk or have a commit button somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I Found the solution, inside my _toggleTodo i need it to save my TodoList after doing something to my todo.